# Recursive tree, printing ancestor nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm

this is study material, not homework:

I have the following tree, I need to write an algorithm that finds a given number and returns an integer indicating how many nodes it visited before finding it. It should also print the values of all "ancestor" nodes relative to the node in which the value was found (in no particular order, and it is assumed that the given value is always present)

```
            10
           /  \
         20    60
        /  \ 
       50  30
             \
             40
```

If the given value is 40 it should return 4 and print 30, 20, 10 (in any order)

I've written the following solution, and I think it works, but I'm concerned about the print.

```
void foobar (ty_tree *tree, int value, int & count){
    if (tree !=null) {
        if (tree->value != value) {
            count++;
            foobar (tree->left, value, count);
            foobar (tree->right, value, count);
            cout << tree->value;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are doing this recursively, you only want to print the value of the node when you are descending from finding the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good approach ! But to print the ancestors (i.e.parent nodes) you need to know in your recursive function if the value was found in one of the child:

```
bool foobar (ty_tree *tree, int value, int & count) {
    if (tree !=nullptr) {  // oops: NULL or nullptr, the latter is better
        if (tree->value != value) {
            count++;
            if (foobar (tree->left, value, count) ||
                  foobar (tree->right, value, count) ) // if found below
            cout << tree->value<<endl;  // print the node, because it's on the path          
        }
        else {
            cout << "Found: "<<tree->value<<endl;  // print the value found
            return true;     // and inform caller that he can print as well.
        }
    } 
    else return false;  // reached a leaf without finding        
}
```

As some doubts were expressed in the comments, here an [online demo](http://ideone.com/nJmZEL)

Comment: Close, but this doesn't print ancestors, it prints in-order predecessors.

Comment: @gene doesn't it print 40, 30, 20, 10 as expected by op ?

Comment: Awesome! I'm just learning recursion so I don't quite understand this part:
        
                if (foobar (tree->left, value, count) || foobar (tree->right, value, count)

Is the program first calling with left pointer, then calling with right pointer and finally evaluating if true or false?

Comment: Thanks ! No, it doesn't evaluate both parts if it is not needed. Instead it uses the magic of [the logical or `||`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx): first it tries the left; if it is true it executes the if-block.  Only if it's false (aka not found on left) it tries the right.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to say, I forgot to add that it wouldn't call with right pointer if left pointer call was true (as in this particular example). Thanks a lot man! This problem was giving me a headache!